# $\det(\mathbf{1} - c \mathbf{J}_n)$, where $\mathbf{J}_n$ is an $n\times n$ matrix of ones

Tags: determinant

Let $\mathbf{J}_n$ be an $n\times n$ matrix of ones, and let $c$ be a real number. Compute the following determinant:

$$\det(\mathbf{1} - c \mathbf{J}_n)$$

where $\mathbf{1}$ denotes the $n\times n$ identity matrix.

$n$ is a positive integer, of course.

Comment: hint: eigenvalues if you are allow to, otherwise induction over $n$.

Comment: @user251257 How can I use eigenvalues here?

Comment: $1 - c J_n$ is symmetric, thus diagonalizable. The eigenvalues of $J_n$ are $0$ and $n$ (why? $0$ only if $n>1$).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Show that $\det(id-cJ_n)=1-nc$ by induction. For $n=1$, $id-cJ_1=(1-c)$, so the determinant is $1-c$.

Another way is to see that $id-cJ_n$ is a symmetric matrix of a very special kind, where more general determinant formulas are known.

Comment: Can you expand on the known "more general determinant formulas"?

Comment: See for (symmetric) [Toeplitz matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toeplitz_matrix) and its determinants.